# Can I safely remove this buzzer from a UPS PCB?

Tags: repair

I want to remove this buzzer from this UPS PCB. It's very noisy.

For the UPS to continue working, should I just remove the buzzer with a soldering iron? or do I have to put some wire or resistance in-place?

[image: Front side]

[image: back side]

Comment: "For **it** to continue working, should I just remove **it**..."  I know I'm nitpicking, but while I'm pretty sure you mean for **the UPS** to continue working, should I just remove **the buzzer**" it would be nice if you would _edit your question_ for clarity on this point.

Comment: Do you want to _remove the sounder_ or _reduce the noise_?

Comment: I removed the buzzer, the UPS still works fine. I might add a resistor & an LED later to know error codes. Thanks.

Comment: Why did the manufacturer include a buzzer the the UPS at all? Presumably it sounds - perhaps in some sort of blink or morse code - when 1) the main power fails and you're now running on the UPS battery 2) it sounds when the UPS battery is in a discharged state 3) something else is _wrong_. Why would you want to disable this device that is urgently trying to bring a fault condition to your attention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be harder to build the UPS so that it would stop working with the buzzer removed than to build it so that it doesn't notice whether the buzzer is there or not.

Whether someone decided to make it "notice" -- that's up to the UPS manufacturer.  If you can figure out how to test your work, take it off and see what happens -- then put it back in if needs be.

Answer (score 3):

Often with these sounders an easy way to reduce the sound level is to place a piece of tape over the hole.

No soldering, no damage of the device/PCB and to revert back to how it was is just as easy by removing the tape.

Comment: I tried the tape method before it was still too loud for me. Thanks.